# Low pass filter implementation with programmable cut-off frequency for inclinometer

Tags: lowpass-filter

My application is an inclinometer. I would like to design a low pass filter with programmable cut-off frequency ranging from 0.1Hz to 20Hz using CMSIS DSP library provided by ARM. The filter may be critically damped and butterworth with an order of 1, 4 and 8. The sampling rate of the sensor can be configured between 100Hz to 1600Hz. How can I implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed sampling rate somewhere between mentioned?

Comment: Yes, the sampling rate will be fixed; typically 100Hz or 200Hz used.

Comment: Maybe this GitHub project helps you to start with filter (coefficient) calculations : https://github.com/ruohoruotsi/Butterworth-Filter-Design . As CMSIS DSP library has needed commands for the processing part, use those calculated coefficients in parameters.

Comment: Which type of filter (FIR or IIR) do you recommend? As I know, IIR filters may not be stable. Need more suggestions?

Comment: Probably both works well for your application ... Both methods has their weaknesses. IIR is unstable when order is high ... this can be rounded by converting 4th and 8th order filters into second order sections (SOS) as what those functions found in CMSIS DSP suggests to use.